# DB design help for simple product and materials situation

Tags: database-design

I currently have 3 simple tables: products (prodid, name and prodmatid), materials (matid, name) and prodmat (prodmatid, prodid and matid).

I am not sure if the above is a good design. Products can consist of different materials, the prodmat table only allows for one material at a time for a product - so if productA has 5 materials then it will require 5 rows in prodmat. Is this a silly way of doing it, how should I design this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your design, it looks like you have an extra column that is not needed in the `products` table. You can remove the `prodmatid` column since you can find that relationship in the `prodmat` table.

So your structure would be: `products (prodid, name)`, `materials (matid, name)`, and `prodmat (prodmatid, prodid, matid)`

This allows for a product 'My Product', materials 'Material 1' and 'Material 2', and the result would be:

```
product (1, 'My Product')
material (1, 'Material 1'), material (2, 'Material 2')
prodmat (1, 1, 1), prodmat (2, 1, 2)
```

Comment: Why the surrogate key on `prodmat`? You can just use a composite PK on `prodid, matid`

Comment: thanks guys, so basically: products (prodid, name), materials (matid, name), and prodmat (prodid, matid). The prodmatid does not serve any purpose and would not be needed?

Comment: @njk The surrogate key is just habit, it doesn't really need to be there. However, if you are going to have an index, or do some update/delete operations, by a single id is ideal.

Answer (score 0):

This is called `third normal form` and is the **accepted way** to design a relational database.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form

**EDIT**

Some people (including myself) would remove the `prodmatid` from the material table, as `prodid` and `matid` can be used as the primary key.  Other people like to have 1 unique primary key for each table.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is not homework... I'd do something like this:

Table: Products
Prodid (PK), Name 
(I suppose some extra column would come handy... like... shelf-life? needs-special-storage?)

Table: Materials
Matid (PK), Name, unit-of-measure (is it in grams, kilos, meters, items...)
(Again, price? shelf-life?)

Table: ProdMat 
PK: Prodit+MAtid, Prodit (FK), Matid (FK), Quantity.

So, going back to your example, let's see product Gizmo:

```
Products Table
Prodid  | Name
  00203 | Gizmo
```

It is made of 5 different "materials":

```
Table: ProdMat 
Prodit | Matid | Qty
 00203 | 0034  | 2
 00203 | 0010  | 11
 00203 | 0567  | 1 
 00203 | 0002  | 1
 00203 | 0039  | 1.675
```

and these are:

```
Table: Materials
 Matid | Name                  | u-o-m 
 0034  | Cogs, brass, diam.2"  | Units
 0010  | Spring, small         | Units
 0567  | Gizmo shell (lower)   | Units 
 0002  | Gizmo shell (upper)   | Units
 0039  | Sand                  | Pounds
```

Now, if your problems includes sub-assemblies, or stuff that gets in as raw material and can undergo internal processing to become refined, or machined, or anyway transformed into one or more semi-processed materials/products than may become in turn parts of another Product... then things start getting interesting.